# Facebook 'like' button doesn't show when linking to my Facebook page - it works for every other page

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I want to have a Facebook like button on my website homepage (http://www.jrosworld.com/) to like the corresponding Facebook page for this website (https://www.facebook.com/pages/Jros-World-travel-blog/249567488395870).

It used to work but it stopped some time ago, and through testing different things have found that the button appears on my site for seemingly any page except the one that I want it to.

If the data in the href tag links to my websites homepage, the button appears on my site. If I link it to my Facebook profile, the button appears. But when I put the link to website's Facebook page into the href tag, the button no longer appears on my site.

Can anyone help me with ideas as to why?

I've tried searching for answers extensively, but haven't found anything yet, and most people write with language that is way beyond what I can understand (I keep on seeing something about app ID and admin ID, but I don't really understand what this means).

Furthermore, when creating the button on the Facebook developer page, the button appears correctly, with the correct number of likes (25) that my page currently has. It just doesn't appear on my sites homepage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I feel like an idiot. After about a month of thinking, I was having a shower this morning and I finally figured out the problem.

This Facebook page is not available to people in Thailand. I live in Thailand.